# public method called from inside self object javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there a way to call public method from jquery button click configured inside the same object?? below I show you the multiple way I have been tried

```
var myClass = new MyClass();

function MyClass() {
   this.func1 = function () {
      alert("Hello World");
   }

   var me = this;    
   $("#my-button").click(function(){
      //func1(); //dont work (wold like)
      //this.func1(); //dont work (would like)
      me.func1();   //Work! but is not correct way to do it
      myClass.func1(); //Work! but the idea its that recognize itself widthout call public   instance
  });
}
```

Other way to do??

Comment: _me.func1();   //Work! but is not correct way to do it_ What's wrong with this way?

Comment: What do you mean by a "public method"?

Comment: @ParthThakkar I was going to ask the identical question

Comment: Javascript is Javascript, don't try to force it work like another language (java for example).

Answer (score 2):

me.func1() is actually the correct way to do it, although I believe convention is to name it "self" instead of "me".

Comment: best practice? on what basis? call it a convention.

Comment: haha I have no basis, that's why I preceded with "I believe". Agreed convention is better.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
var myClass = new MyClass();

function MyClass() {
   var myFunc = function () {
      alert("Hello World");
   }
   this.func1 = myFunc;

   $("#my-button").click(function(){
      myFunc();  
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `this` inside the click handler refers to `my-button`, `this.func1()` won't work. `func1()` won't work because when the click handler is eventually triggered it will be in a different context and `func1()` doesn't make any sense in that context. Your solution is good.